# How can I use diff or any other command to compare two text files

Tags: diff

I have two large files (2gig each) listed and sorted randomly, and I need to find difference between them and write to an output file:

file-1:

```
abc1234
def4321
ghi1234
```

file-2:

```
ghi1234
jk16754
abc1234
mnop3847
```

output:

```
def4321
jk16754
mnop3847
```

Comment: So you want to `sort` both files according to the same sorting order before `diff`?

Comment: Do you want to select lines that are in file-1 and file-2 but lines that are in both files should be dropped?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ join -v 1 -v 2 <( sort file-1 ) <( sort file-2 )
def4321
jk16754
mnop3847
```

`join` performs a relational JOIN operation on its sorted input files (using the first tab-delimited column in each file, but this may be changed on the command line, see the manual).  It outputs the matching data by default, but with `-v 1` and `-v 2` we may get the lines from each file that does *not* match in the other file.

If your shell does not support process substitution with `<(...)`, then sort the files beforehand. You may want to do this anyway if you plan to run the command several times or do other work on the files.

```
$ sort -o file-1.sorted file-1
$ sort -o file-2.sorted file-2
$ join -v 1 -v 2 file-[12].sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `comm` and `sed` can do what you're looking for.

[`comm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) compares to files and outputs 3 columns.  Column 1 is all the lines only in file1, column 2 is all the lines only in file2, and column 3 is common lines.

In your case, you want to suppress the printing of column 3, and then use sed to strip the whitespace from the entries in column 2.

```
bash-[533]$ comm -3 <(sort file-1) <(sort file-2) | sed -e 's/^\s*//'
def4321
jk16754
mnop3847
```

`comm` does require that the files are sorted, and the example above shows the files being sorted on the fly, with the output sent to a file descriptor, but you could pre-sort your files which may be easier on your system resources, and run the command as:

```
bash-[533]$ comm -3 file-1-sorted file-2-sorted | sed -e 's/^\s*//'
def4321
jk16754
mnop3847
```

Comment: The first two options worked for me:

`    $ join -v 1 -v 2 <( sort file-1 ) <( sort file-2 )def4321
    jk16754
    mnop3847`

AND diff option worked as well:

***`diff --changed-group-format="%>%<" --unchanged-group-format="" <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Answer (score 0):

With ***diff*** command:

```
diff --changed-group-format="%>%<" --unchanged-group-format="" <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

The output:

```
def4321
jk16754
mnop3847
```